# How to be able to embed a graphical application inside another

Tags: java, c#, c++, windows, winapi

I'm looking for some ideas on the general architecture for creating a Windows application (I'm open to suggestions: Java, C++, C# and also for frameworks) in which I can show another application running inside of it. Very similar to the iframe concept, where a web page is rendered within the frame.

I think I would need to instal the framed application as part of a custom installer, or even assume it is preinstalled in the OS. The important part initially is to be able to framed a graphical application inside another.

Comment: If you mean one process hosting a window from another process, that is hard to do, and not properly supported. You should find a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. see this examples:  [andy](http://www.andyroid.net/) , [bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

Comment: Those are Android virtualization programs. What exactly is your question? It would seem to me that your question is far too broad.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. basically is to make a similar functionality as iframes behave, but in this case between applications

Comment: It's far too broad a question. You need to be more focused when asking here. Please read the site help.